# SmartSVN how to revert ignored files

Tags: svn, ignore, smartsvn

I ignored a few files using SmartSVN. Now, I want to revert this changes. I read that the following command can be used:

```
svn propdel svn:ignore -R
```

But There is error: "The path '.' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy."

What is the best way to revert ignore operation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To undo the ignore, you can use SmartSVN: just right click the directory in which the ignored files reside, in the pop-up menu choose `Properties -> Ignore Patterns...`

You will get to the dialog, which shows all file patterns set to be ignored. Remove the ones not needed and save. Locally it will be effective immediately, but you have to commit this property change (the directory) to make this change permanent in the repository.

Comment: pop-up menu is empty. It sounds ok because there is no patters.

Comment: Which popup is empty? What the ignore operation does is that it adds the pattern into the ignore patterns on the parent of the ignored file. So if your files are really ignored (not shown), then they must be in the ignore pattern. Please note, that there are some filter icons in top-right of your file list, first of which is to list files deep in directories - so the files you ignored could be somewhere deep in the dir structure. The directory with the ignore set should be pink in the Directories tree.

Comment: Great ! Now I understand what is going on. If you ignore file folderA/folderB/fileC.txt you have to right click on folderB, when you click on folderA nothing will be shown. Dzięki Michale :)

Comment: A word of warning: If an ignore pattern is applied recursively, I see no easy way to undo this action. Specifically, that recursive ignore seems to have REMOVED ignores that were in subfolders. (Unless there is is some other reason unversioned files deep down would suddenly become visible when adding new ignore patterns.) Don't see any way to restore those, without knowing exactly what they were and where.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Given that SmartSVN does not seem to allow recursive ignores, I assume you used command line `propset` command recursively. If so, you should be able to revert all the affected directories with `--depth empty` which should restore to your original `svn:ignores` (assuming you did not make any other prop changes). You would need to use some script to do all dirs one-by-one (as recursive revert would also revert other changes).